# How to make Magento to get prices as per user group?

Tags: magento

Need 3 pricing levels. One is public and the other two are assigned to the user and shown after login.

How can I accomplish this in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

this is a feature in magento 1.7 that will be released soon so I guess eithr use release candidate or wait for a release

Comment: if i want to do it in 1.61  do you know how to do it? thank you

Comment: easier to upgrade than implement

Answer (score 0):

You can assign pricing levels to user groups. We have normal pricing, dealer, and distributor. Look in admin menu: Catalog (click on a product) Then in left column, Prices. In the main window is orange "+ Add Tier" button. You use this to dictate quantity discounts (for any customer group) and also to apply discounted pricing for Customer Groups.

I'm using version 1.4.2 and all of this is part of the item creation process.